# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 3 > 3

Tags: android, realm, mpandroidchart

I am facing a problem using `MpAndroidChart` with `Realm` making graph and it throws an Exception. I want to have date of measuring on `XAxis` and body fat % on `YAxis`. I have looked into the Android Device Monitor and data is saved normaly, under id 1 correct String date and float `fatPercent` and under id 2 ...and so on. More info below. Here is my code:

```
public class DataFatPercent extends RealmObject {


    private float id;
    private String date;
    private float fatPercent;

    public DataFatPercent() {

    }

    public DataFatPercent(float id, String date, float fatPercent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.fatPercent = fatPercent;
    }
```

with setters and getters...

My activity:

```
public class FatGraphProgressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView dodaj_podatke_grafu;
    private LineChart lineChart;
    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<DataFatPercent> results;
    protected Typeface mTf;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fat_graph_progress);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
        setup(lineChart);


            lineChart.setExtraBottomOffset(5f);
            lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
            lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
            lineChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(5);
            lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1f);





        dodaj_podatke_grafu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dodajpodatkevgraf);
        dodaj_podatke_grafu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Calling dialog,where I put data and save in realmbase
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddFatProcentDialog afpd = new AddFatProcentDialog();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                afpd.show(transaction,"dialog");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        setData();

    }

    public void setData(){

        results = realm.where(DataFatPercent.class).findAll();

        AxisValueFormatter formatter = new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return results.get((int) value).getDate();
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        };

        lineChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(formatter);

        RealmLineDataSet<DataFatPercent> lineDataSet = new RealmLineDataSet<>(results,"id","fatPercent");

        lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(false);
        lineDataSet.setLabel("Result Scores");
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        lineDataSet.setColor(ColorTemplate.rgb("#FF5722"));
        lineDataSet.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.rgb("#FF5722"));
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(1.8f);
        lineDataSet.setCircleSize(3.6f);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
        styleData(lineData);

        // set data
        lineChart.setData(lineData);
        lineChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);

    }
```

And dialog,when I click on image to saveData:

```
public void save_data(){

        float id = 0;
        if(results.size()>0){
            id = results.max("id").floatValue();
        }
        newId = id + 1;
        String add_date = this.add_date.getText().toString();
        String percentoffat = add_fat_procent_data.getText().toString();
        float fat_percent_float = Float.parseFloat(percentoffat);

        realm.beginTransaction();
        dataFatPercent = new DataFatPercent(newId,add_date,fat_percent_float);
        podatkiOseb.getFatProcents().add(dataFatPercent);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();

    }

    private View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            switch (id){
                case R.id.potrdiprocentmascobe:
                    save_data();

            }
            dismiss();
        }
    };

}
```

In short, it throws this error in method getFormattedValue:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex >
>   available rows: 3 > 3
>                                                                                                     at io.realm.internal.TableView.nativeGetSourceRowIndex(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at io.realm.internal.TableView.getSourceRowIndex(TableView.java:128)
>                                                                                                     at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:205) at
>   com.example.draganmaric.tablayoutswipescroll.FatGraphProgressActivity$2.getFormattedValue(FatGraphProgressActivity.java:89)

I have also noticed, if I change in `setData` method

```
 results = realm.where(DataFatPercent.class).findAll();
```

with `findallAsync`, it doesn't throw exception(it opens activity), but I don't see any graph on the screen. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Use findAllAsync with callback, show the data on graphs from the callback function

Comment: Hi Luca, tanx for respond. I totaly forgot about it. Ok, I know how to put this part onChange(Object element) and set it onStart as results.addChangeListener(changeListener); But I dont know what to put (how to use results) in public void onChange function. Any advice?

Comment: Just had a rapid look 'cause I can't spend much time atm, I guess you need to call "ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
        styleData(lineData);

        // set data
        lineChart.setData(lineData);
        lineChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);" these parts inside the callback method

Comment: Luca,tanx for the answer. But I am still looking for solution...Not working. Something is not set right that does not show graph.

Comment: Which realm version are you using? We used to have a similar problem which has been fixed in `v1.0.1` . https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2990

Comment: Hi Beeender, I am using this :  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"......And this support in gradle app:   compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart-Realm:v1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'.  I dont get it, why it doesn't show...

Comment: @DMdeveloping Really sorry for the late response. Are you still able to reproduce the issue? If you don't mind, we can help to debug it if you can share your project to help@realm.io

Comment: Hi beender,no problem. Yes,I am...Still not showing graph.Thath would be great.

Comment: With help of  realm team, special thanks goes to beeender, I have found a solution if someone is having the same problem. The index of RealmResults is began with 0, but the first number it passed to getFormattedValue is 1 which will cause the crash when it called with the last element of the results.
It works with: return results.get((int) value - 1).getDate();  After that,just change back to findAll(); and works.   Again, thank you realm team! :)